# Spring Security - AuthenticatedPricipal deprecated

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

Spring Security version: `spring-boot-starter-security:1.3.0.RC1`

Noticing that the annotation `@AuthenticationPrincipal` has been deprecated.

Possible different way to accomplish the same thing and wondering if this is the correct way to get user information within a Spring MVC Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndex(HttpSession session, Device device, Model model, Principal principal) {

    /**
     * Spring Security Fetch User
     */
    if (principal != null) {
        String username = principal.getName();
        User currentUser = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        model.addAttribute("user", currentUser.getFirstName());
    }

    return "view";

}
```

On another note I found not having the `HttpSession session` would result in stale sessions causing page load errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The annotation has been moved to another package.

Use `org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal` instead of the deprecated `org.springframework.security.web.bind.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal`.

Answer (score -1):

The below code snippet should work

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndex(HttpSession session, Device device, Model model) {

    /**
     * Spring Security Fetch User
     */

    User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = user.getUsername();
    User currentUser = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
    model.addAttribute("user", currentUser.getFirstName());

    return "view";

}
```

You can avoid calling userRepostiory(database, a duplicate call) by extending User Class and creating field firstName